# Prepopulate django form leads to 'str' object has no attribute 'get'

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I was trying to prefill django 2 form for updating a model

```
def update_profile(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UpdateProfile(request.POST, instance=request.user.userprofile)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('index')
    else:
        form = UpdateProfile(instance=request.user.userprofile)

    return render(request, 'update_profile.html', args)
```

But it leads to

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/forms/widgets.py", line 254, in value_from_datadict
    return data.get(name)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'



class UpdateProfile(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(UpdateProfile, self).__init__(*args, *kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper(self)

        self.helper.form_method = "post"
        self.helper.form_action = "/preferences"
        self.helper.add_input(Submit('save', 'Save'))

    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ["age", "gender", "phone", "genre_pref"]
```

I have also tried UpdateProfile(initial=model_to_dict(request.user)) instead of UpdateProfile(instance=request.user)

Any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: What's the code in `UpdateProfile`?

Comment: `request.user` is `User` object (usually), not a `UserProfile`. I suspect you should pass `instance=request.user.user_profile` or something like that. How are your `User` and `UserProfile` models defined?

Comment: yeah, sorry that was a old code, I have updated it

Comment: also, what is `args` in `return render(request, 'update_profile.html', args)`?

Comment: args = {'form': form}

Comment: Is the error when you submit the form or render it? (i.e on GET or POST)? Also showing more lines of your traceback would help, so we can see which method in your code is called causing the error.

Comment: you're still setting `instance=request.user` in the `GET` (`else`) part of your view.

Comment: The error occurs in GET, while rendering the form. the request.user was because i was trying all permutations hoping something would work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168250/discussion-between-darkcoderrises-and-dirkgroten).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
super(UpdateProfile, self).__init__(*args, *kwargs)
```

should be

```
super(UpdateProfile, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```